# How do I automatically refresh the spreadsheet name upon update?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have the following script to retrieve the name of my spreadsheet (not sheet) name:

```
function sheetName() {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
}
```

However, due to memoization this does not update automatically when I change the spreadsheet name. Is there a way automatically update when the spreadsheet name changes?

I am aware of workarounds such as referencing a cell to pass a dummy value to the function that can be changed to force the script to run. I'm looking for something that requires no more work than changing the spreadsheet name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no trigger that runs when the spreadsheet name is changed (unlike for sheet name changes, which trigger a Change event.) The only way to keep up-to-date spreadsheet name in a script is to fetch the name by a timed trigger, e.g., every 5 minutes.

Comment: A trigger doesn't even help - it doesn't rerun the function in the cell.

Comment: So it can't be a custom function, but rather a script function that will set a cell value directly with setValue.

Comment: Could you provide an example?